# How to use sockets on objc?

Tags: objective-c, sockets, ip, p2p

I want to use p2p in my game. How can I get IP adress and use sockets on objc?
Please help me.

Comment: Anything you can do in C you can do in Objective-C.  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Are you talking iPhone or OSX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS X includes standard BSD sockets. Type `man socket` in the Terminal for the socket API docs.

Answer (score 1):

Use raw BSD sockets as you have always done. But are you sure you do not want to use a better abstraction provided by Core Foundation or Foundation?

I think you should look at session 207 and 208 of WWDC 2010, where Quinn "the Eskimo!" details proper, safe and efficient networking on iOS.

http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/